# Rotate a div in jQuery and stopping it with value recieved from server

Tags: jquery, html, css-animations

I am rotating a div using keyframe animation and is working fine. While the div is rotating I am waiting for a server response and once I recieve a response (which will be an angle) I want to stop the div at that particular angle.

I tried to remove the class which is animating but when I do that the div coming back to its orignal position with a visual flick and then resting at my required place.

Here is the jsFiddle for that http://jsfiddle.net/bVkwH/3/

jQuery :

```
$("#stop").click(function () {
    var pos = $(".pos").val();
    $("#bg > img").removeClass('animate');
    $("#bg > img").css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + pos + 'deg)'
    });
    $("#bg > img").css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + pos + 'deg)'
    });
});

$("#start").click(function () {
    $("#bg > img").addClass('animate');        
});
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bg > img {
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s;
}
#bg > img.animate {
    -webkit-animation: spinIt 6s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spinIt 6s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinIt {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinIt {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Any solutions for that.. I want this to work on iPad browsers.. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just use jQuery UI to spin it, not CSS.  Using CSS in this case (rotating to a specific angle post server-response) is going to be overly complicated.

Comment: I have been using the fiddle that you posted in FF, but i don't see the image(spinner) animating when i click the start button or enter any value to the text box and then click it. Are you sure, this is correct or am i missing something here ?

Comment: @dark Knight - The image rotates by default. The start button is to restart after stopping the spin. The text box specifies at which angle it should be stopped. Thankx !

Answer (score 1):

Remove class animate after setting css properties.

**Edit:** As Richard points out it does not work.
It is possible to get value, but some conversation from matrix to degrees will be needed to do the final part of animation.

```
$("#stop").click(function () {
    var iimg = $("#bg > img");
    // get current transformation
    var ccss = getComputedStyle(iimg.get(0));
    var matrix = ccss.getPropertyValue('transform') || ccss.getPropertyValue('-moz-transform') || ccss.getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform');
    // get wanted new value
    var pos = $(".pos").val();

    // stop css transformation
    iimg.removeClass('transtime');
    iimg.css({
        '-webkit-transform': matrix,
        '-moz-transform': matrix,
        'transform': matrix,
    });
    iimg.removeClass('animate');
```

Some css and Markup updates is needed for this as well.
http://jsfiddle.net/bVkwH/4/

Comment: How do you determine the angle at which to remove the class?  The server is supposed to give an angle and the client stop the rotation at that angle.

Comment: @Richard yes, misunderstanding on my part at first. Not a solution but might at least help.

Comment: I googled for conversion matrix. I got a solution as well though its nt of much help. Thanks for the fiddle. I ll give a try !